# Multiple templates with FuncMap

Tags: templates, text, go

The Goal: using multiple templates in an HTTP server where I want to change newlines into `<br/>` tags on some strings.

A stripped down example:

I have two templates `a.tmpl` and `b.tmpl` which look like this:

```
Template a {{dosomething}}
```

(and similar the other template). Both reside in a directory called `templates`. I believe that I need to create a function to do the `\n` -> `<br />` replacement (`dosomething` above).

This is my (non working) sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    // funcMap := template.FuncMap{
    //  "dosomething": func() string { return "done something" },
    // }

    templates, err := template.ParseGlob("templates/*.tmpl")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%#v", templates)

}
```

The error message is:

```
2013/03/04 20:08:19 template: a.tmpl:1: function "dosomething" not defined
exit status 1
```

which makes sense, because during the parsing time, the function `dosomething` is not known.

1. How can I use my function in multiple templates? Is the answer to [this question here on so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199219/go-template-function) the only way to go?
2. Is this the correct approach? Remember, I'd like to change the text on some strings, similar to the title example in the documentation (http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#FuncMap - Example (Func))?
3. How do I access `b.tmpl` in the following code:

   ```
   package main

   import (
       "log"
       "text/template"
   )

   func main() {
       funcMap := template.FuncMap{
           "dosomething": func() string { return "done something" },
       }

       t, err := template.New("a.tmpl").Funcs(funcMap).ParseGlob("templates/*.tmpl")
       if err != nil {
           log.Fatal(err)
       }
       log.Printf("%#v", t)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last snippet of code looks about right to me.

To render b.tmpl, just call

```
t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "b.tmpl", data)
```

You can access a.tmpl the same way; I would recommend doing this for consistency, rather than setting the name to "a.tmpl" in the call to New.

Comment: I don't quite understand the second part of your answer - how to access `a.tmpl` the same way. I need to call `Funcs(funcMap)` something like "inbetween" a new and `ParseGlob(...)`

Comment: @topskip I meant that you should render template a by calling t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "a.tmpl", data) rather than by calling t.Execute(w, data). That way the two templates are treated equally. Then you can give the set of all the templates a better name than "a.tmpl".

Comment: This is what I have now: `t, err := template.New("").Funcs(funcMap).ParseGlob("templates/*.tmpl")` and then `t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "b.tmpl", "hello")` - this works fine. Same with the other template. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, applying Funcs to multiple templates isn't documented anywhere

Comment: So, what's the point of `template.New("<this part>")`? Does the parameter for `template.New` not matter if we use `t.ExecuteTemplate` instead of `t.Execute`?

Comment: With template.New, you're just creating a base template—a container to hold the other templates. So, right, the name doesn't really matter. I do `template.New("root")`.

Comment: Worth pointing out also, as done in @topskip's example, you have to run `.Funcs(..)` before any `.Parse*(..)`, otherwise the template will not be aware of the functions.